# Find the inverse of $2$ modulo $17$ using the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

The question states "find the inverse of a modulo m for each of these pairs of relatively prime integers"

**ATTEMPT AT SOLUTION**
\begin{align*}
17 & = 2 \cdot 8 + 1\\
2 & = 1 \cdot 2
\end{align*}

Thus, $\gcd(2, 17) = 1$ and it does have an inverse

Reversing the Euclidean expansion, I get
$$1 = 17 \cdot 1 - 2 \cdot 8$$

and thus the Bézout coefficients of $2$ and $17$ are $1$ and $-8$, and the inverse of $2$ modulo $17$ is $8$.

However, when I check my answer, the inverse of $2$ modulo $7$ is $9$!
Please tell me what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: You proved that $2\cdot 8\equiv \color{red}{-1}\pmod{17}$, so the inverse of $2$ is $-8\equiv 9$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that you *actually* got

$$1=17\cdot1+2\cdot(-8)\implies -8=2^{-1}\pmod{17}$$

but of course $\;-8=9\pmod{17}\;$ , so you only had a tiny sign mistake.